# Is there a way to turn the Windows ghosting feature back on after DisableProcessWindowsGhosting?

Tags: windows, winapi

We have an application that do heavy work in the main thread. To prevent Windows from deeming it 'Not Responding' and starting the ghosting feature (as described in section 'Hangs - Operating System Perspective' in this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd744765%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) during the heavy work, we could use [DisableProcessWindowsGhosting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648415%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to turn the ghosting feature off.

But we don't want to turn it off for the rest of the session, we want to turn it back on once the heavy work is done. Unfortunately Windows doesn't provide any (documented) API for that.

Is there any (possibly hacky) way to turn it back on?

As an interesting note, when the application runs in VC debugger, the ghosting feature is turned off, but once the it's detached, it's back on. There must be something the debugger does, any idea?

Comment: It's not really a good idea to disable ghosting, even temporarily.  Doing so seriously messes up the user interface - the user can't minimize or move your window, and the window won't be redrawn if another application's window is moved over top of it.

Comment: I can't believe they even *have* that functionality to begin with... it defeats the entire purpose of ghosting!

Comment: @Mehrdad: some kind of backwards compatibility issue, I suppose.

Comment: We don't have much of a choice here, it's too expensive to move the heavy work to a different thread.

Comment: @ducktail: You mean too expensive as in money/workforce? Or by expensive do you mean computation time/resources?

Comment: @Mehrdad: too expensive architecturally, so money/workforce. The application hasn't be designed with keeping an idle main thread in mind.

Comment: Why do you need to prevent ghosting from occurring?

Comment: It's possible that ghosting is automatically disabled for any process with a debugger connected; that would seem reasonable.  I guess you could try getting the process to connect to itself as a debugger, or you could launch a separate process to do so.  I still think the user would be better off if you just let ghosting occur as normal.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: When it occurs, the user will feel that something's wrong and will likely attempt to stop it, but nothing is actually wrong, it just needs a few more seconds. Connecting itself as a debugger looks cool, how do I do that?

Comment: I rather think the users will notice anyway, because when they switch back to the application from whatever else they're doing they'll see your frame with the other application's content inside, which looks a whole bunch more broken than a ghosted window does.  That said, look up the DebugActiveProcess function.  A process probably can't actually debug itself, though, so I expect you'll need to launch a subprocess to do it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: shouldn't you write an answer explaining how badly this would fail?

Comment: @wqw: That's a rather strong claim to make without pointing out a single specific flaw in his reasoning...

Comment: @SamB: The users are not going to see OP frame w/ other apps content inside as dmw will restore cached content -- just tested it in a real app w/ ghosting disabled. There can be a perfect reason for an app to disable OS ghosting on long running operations, for instance to be able to queue keyboard input during long operations which otherwise gets consumed by abort/retry dialog which OS displays after 5 sec. He is assuming too much of OPs app requirements and blindly regurgitating "advice" from MSDN provided articles w/o 1st hand experience w/ this particular API, doing OP a bad favor IMO.

Comment: Another reason why one might want to turn of ghosting is because it seriously messes up the Z-Order of windows once the application becomes responsive again because activation events are partially gobbled up by the ghost windows and the wrong window is reactivated upon "un-ghosting". (see for example https://community.progress.com/s/article/P186860) 
For us this lead to an owner window being drawn in front of the owned windows. Disabling ghosting fixed these issues reliably.

Comment: @HarryJohnston actually it is *the opposite*!!! before the ghosting kicks in the window *is redrawing itself* and the user *does see* the changes, like gauge bars filling up, etc. After Windows threw the ghost instead of the real window - the user *no more sees* the updates. The window DOES update itself to show status changes to the user, but the *user can no more see* it because Windows prohibited it. For the record: implementing multithreading there would be very complex and fragile.

Comment: What makes it yet more "consistent" is that if i click another application (switch focus) then the busy window works as expected - it is NOT ghosted out and the user can see status updates. But if the user keeps the application focused (and why should them not) - then the Windows hides update notifications from them.

Comment: @Arioch'The, under what circumstances does a window that is still redrawing itself get ghosted?  It isn't immediately clear to me how that could happen.

Comment: @HarryJohnston redrawing is not the window (Form) itself but certain controls (widgets) (which AFAIR is called "child windows" in Use32 API parliance). You call `UpdateWindow` on them in a long loop five times per second (GetTickCount-based throttling) and they do updating themselve for 5 seconds, until their "mother window" gets ghosted. Notice, how both MSDN and Raymond Chen tie ghosting to `PeekMessage` function, but `UpdateWindow` function is not said to call `PeekMessage` but to directly call `WndProc`. So even if you qouls do `UpdateWindow` in loop to the "user-perceived" window i am not

Comment: sure this would reliably prevent ghosting. But, will it or not, i am prtetty sure it would NOT prevent ghosting if you `InvalidateWindow`/`UpdateWindow` of the widget inside the window. To "minimize drag" i ended with repainting (*invalidate+update*) selected controls, and then doing sole *update* to the window itself (which most times would be no-op). It all worked fine for me during debugging, for IDE had focus not the debugged app. Until QA run the app without debugger and kept it focused, then ghosting kicked in disregarding minor redraws ever 20 msec. Adding `PeekMesssage(WM_NULL)` fixed

Answer (score 2):

Disregarding the fact, that doing heavy work on the UI thread is wrong in itself (heavy work should be done on a separate thread that optionally communicates its progress to the UI), the suggestions below are only for the sake of answering the question, to support the legacy code scenario mentioned in the comments.

`DisableProcessWindowsGhosting` is a one-way road and disables the ghosting feature for the life-time of the process, so the only re-enabling condition is to restart the process as whole.

Otherwise all applications that are being debugged (not just in VC debugger, but any debugger), are also exempted from ghosting. If you wanted to hack this condition, you could make a companion application, that will attach to your application as debugger (`DebugActiveProcess`) during the heavy work, and detach itself (`DebugSetProcessKillOnExit(FALSE)`+`DebugActiveProcessStop`) after it's done. This will degrade performance and can cause problems with elevation, forking and SEH to name a few.

Minimized windows are supposed to be exempted from ghosting as well, but I haven't tested this one myself.